Efficient way to delete session records in SQL Server
We have about 10 tables in production that store information on sessions and logging. We have rules to delete these tables. i.e. Table1 -> need to keep records within 180 days, Table2-> within 7 days, Table 3 and 4 have master detail relationship and need to keep only past 180 days and so on.
Table3 and table5 have about 40 million rows each, all others have less than 100000 rows.
We want to write a script that runs every month to clean this up.
Here's what I thought. Make this table driven i.e. keep count of records that need to be deleted, date, date condition in a table and write a cursor and dynamic SQL to delete 10,000 records based on date. Note: none of the tables have index on dates and I am not allowed to add indexes.
What are your suggestions so that end users won't see the slowness and are there more efficient ways.

SQL Server can deal with millions of rows at the same time; doing in batches of 10,000 is likely to make the process slower, rather than faster. Provided your table is appropriately index, the data engine should be able to find the rows to delete quite easily. Though the table has 40 million rows (tables don't have "records"), you're going to be deleting a small portion of those rows. If we assume linear usage, 40M rows in 6 months means ~222k rows a day, or  ~6.6M rows a month. Tbh, for that amount, you might find that a daily process is far better.

"What are your suggestions so that end users won't see the slowness and are there more efficient ways." Also, run the process outside of business/peak hours.

"Note: none of the tables have index on dates and I am not allowed to add indexes." Then speak to whomever can; if you want this kind of process, knowing when the row dated for is paramount. If you need to do this in a performant way, and clearly that is the expectation, then indexes is step 1. No indexes, no performance.

@ThomA: however, if you try to delete more than 5'000 rows in a single batch, SQL Server might need to escalate its lock to table-level exclusive locks - thus causing wide spread blocking. So using batches of 5'000 rows or less can be beneficial

You can use delete top x syntax. Agree with above though, talk with someone in charge, you're working at same company, nto against each other

If you don't have indexes on dates then you can do a one off upfront scan to get the candidate PKs to delete (based on date) and then can delete batches from that so at least the unindexed stuff only happens once rather than once per batch (and not at a point where it is holding X locks)

I can understand the case for limiting indexes on logging tables to minimize insert overhead. In such cases a prescan as suggested by Martin Smith may be the best way forward. Another possibility might work if the primary key is an identity column that roughly follows ascending date order. In that case, you could start by searching for the cutoff point with something like SELECT TOP 1 LogId FROM LogTable WHERE LogDate >= @RetentionDate ORDER BY LogId. You would then delete all rows with lower LogId values. This approach should avoid a costly full table scan.

I worked in a shop where we also deleted records in batches of 5000. Below is an example of such a strategy, or really two examples, depending on whether or not you can rely on having a always-ascending primary key or not. I also added a third example with an extra safeguard to prevent infinite loops - something I used to worry about when I did this the first couple of times (if you test your scripts properly that shouldn't really be a concern).
I can imagine other variations on this theme, such as collecting the ids in a temp table and then in batches until the ids you want to delete are exhausting - the most important thing is that you have the deletions in batches and that you ensure your loops reaches a break condition.
-- Test Data
set nocount on
drop table if exists #Temp
create table #Temp (
    LogId int not null,
    DateCreated date not null,
    primary key (LogId))

declare @I int = 0
while @I < 100
begin
    set @I += 1
    insert into #Temp (LogId, DateCreated)
        values (@I+1000, DATEADD(day, @I, dateadd(day, -100, getdate())))
end
select 'Before', * from #Temp
set nocount off
go

-- ---------------------------------------------
-- Example One
-- We do not have an ascending primary key, so 
-- we need to use a where condition on the dates
-- ---------------------------------------------
while exists (select * from #Temp where DateCreated < dateadd(day, -30, getdate()))
begin
    begin try
    begin tran
        
        -- delete next batch of records
        -- (i.e, deleting in batches of 5000 at a time)
        delete t
        from #Temp t
        where DateCreated < dateadd(day, -30, getdate())

        commit transaction
        
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        ;throw
    end catch
end
select 'After', * from #Temp
go


-- -----------------------------------------------
-- Example Two
-- We have an ascending primary key, so we can use 
-- a where condition on the primary key
-- -----------------------------------------------
declare @Id int
set @Id = (
    select top (1) LogId from #Temp 
    where DateCreated >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
    order by LogId)
while exists (select * from #Temp where LogId < @Id)
begin
    begin try
    begin tran
        
        delete top (20) t
        from #Temp t
        where LogId < @Id

        commit transaction
    
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        ;throw
    end catch
end
select 'After', * from #Temp
go


-- -----------------------------------------------
-- Example Three
-- Same as example two but including a max iterations
-- cutoff as a precaution - to cap the number of 
-- iterations or as a safeguard against any kind
-- of runaway loops that never break
-- -----------------------------------------------
declare @Id int
declare @MaxIterations int = 1000
declare @Iterations int = 0
set @Id = (
    select top (1) LogId from #Temp 
    where DateCreated >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
    order by LogId)
while exists (select * from #Temp where LogId < @Id)
    and @Iterations < @MaxIterations
begin
    begin try
    begin tran
        
        set @Iterations += 1
        delete top (20) t
        from #Temp t
        where LogId < @Id

        commit transaction
    
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        ;throw
    end catch
end
select 'After', * from #Temp
go

